# SSIS package constantly experiencing the 'Reading stream error - remote connection forcibly closed' to mySQL instance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Hope everyone is well.

I have an Azure SQL Server with a deployed SSIS project to the ssisdb. The project contains multiple packages that run multiple data flows to an on-prem MySQL instance on a Linux environment. Everything has been working fine until recently where packages have been falling over in production with the 'Reading from the stream failed. System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.' This error happens normally with minute or two from start execution time. The thing that makes this hard pin down is the inconsistency in the failures. Most nights it will fail and it won't always be the same package.

The packages are 100% fine. I have a test server with the same Mysql version (5.7 InnoDB) where I've run this with 100% success.

I have added Net_read_timeout & Net_write_timeout settings to 10 mins as it might have been an issue writing many records out to the client and the default settings for MySQL are 30/60 seconds. I concatenated these variables with the SET Session in the ADO.NET MySQLConnector MySqlCommand, so all queries being parsed to the server would set this. Worked for one night and then back to same error. I even tested this locally in SSIS and the net variables don't seem to stop the disconnect. We increased the max_packet_size (Though we don't select any BLOB data) and I think prod batched worked for one night before failing again. I contacted the offshore team that host the Linux environment and they've said nothing on their monitoring tools showing stress or overload on the server during the start of the batch. All they've got is the slow query log and that tells me nothing. I have asked them to enable the general log as I need some information on what's killing the connection. The interactive and wait timeout are both set on the server to 8 hours and the commandTimeout is 1.5 hours.

Really not sure where else to go with this. Only difference between my test server is it an Azure server and their environments are on-prem. I can connect to their server and run these queries fine via workbench. So network issue doesn't seem likely.

Comment: Please post the last 100 lines of your error log.  There may be some clues.

Comment: Hi Wilson, The only entry in the error log is this [Note] Aborted connection 2898 to db: 'bahman' user: 'PORTCDSPR' host: '***.**.***.**' (Got an error writing communication packets).

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
What is Azure type/model in use?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to come back to this. The issue was memory back pressure within the ssis package. Basically the network was sending data packets faster then the package could consume from the network buffer. The server waits for the client to send back that the client has received the data packet successfully. The server will resend the packet (Or wait) but when the threshold is exceeded, the server will kill the connection due to data packet loss. We resolved this by increasing the buffer size in the ssis package (was at default) to read from network buffer faster. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for your feedback and documenting your solution for others to consider.